# I can't run this XNA-based game

Tags: technical-issues, void-rogue

I'm trying to run [this XNA-based game](http://gamejolt.com/games/platformer/void-rogue/12988/) on my Windows 7 32-bit laptop and it just won't run. No error messages, nothing.

If I have the Task Manager open I see the process being executed for a few seconds and disappear.

- Clicking on the game file gives no result.
- I have installed the XNA Frawemork latest version.
- I have tried using the game installer, it installs but the game still won't run, whilst on another computer (Windows 7 32-bit laptop as well), the game runs fine without even needing to install.

Comment: I see I'm getting downvotes. What can I do to improve the quality of this question?

Comment: If the developer himself can't figure out what's wrong, I'm not sure what we can do to help…

Comment: Do you have Games for Windows installed? It's a llllooooonnnnngggggg stretch, but it could be looking for another library that wasn't included in that framework? It's just a guess.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer for any error logs? You might see an .net exception in there

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett How can I check the event viewer?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy Control Panel->Small icons (Just to show administrative tools)->Administrative tools->Event Viewer

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett You nailed it. Please add it as an answer so I can upvote and choose it!

Comment: Turns out the collective minds of [gaming.se] think better than the mind of a single developer. Thanks for the downvotes anyway. I just wanted to know the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xna is built on .Net so there's probably some clue as to what issue is in the event log.

You'll find the event log under administrative tools in the control panel (viewable when control panel is set to "small icons").

Comment: There were a dozen events with Event ID 1026, the most relevant line reading **Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException**. Damn.